# Hybrid recommendation system with matrix factorization and linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery

I'm following a tutorial that for creating a recommendation system in BigQueryML. The tutorial uses matrix factorization first to calculate user and item factors. In the end I have a model that can be queried with user ids or item ids to get recommendations.

The next step is feeding the factors and additional item + user features into a linear regression model to incorporate more context.

> "Essentially, we have a couple of attributes about the movie, the
>   product factors array corresponding to the movie, a couple of
>   attributes about the user, and the user factors array corresponding to
>   the user. These form the inputs to our “hybrid” recommendations model
>   that builds off the matrix factorization model and adds in metadata
>   about users and movies."

I just don't understand why the dataset for linear regression excludes the user and item ids:

```
 SELECT
        p.* EXCEPT(movieId),
        u.* EXCEPT(userId),
        rating 
    FROM productFeatures p, userFeatures u
    JOIN movielens.ratings r
    ON r.movieId = p.movieId AND r.userId = u.userId
```

My question is:
How will I be able to get recommendations for a user from the linear model, when I don't have the user or item ids in the model?

Here you can find the full code:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive2/recommendation_systems/solutions/als_bqml_hybrid.ipynb

Comment: The query you wrote won't return the `moveId` nor the `userId` fields. So any model trained on that data won't recognize those columns. Are you saying that you won't know those fields at predict time? Because that would be a problem (they're needed for the query). If you're just saying that the model doesn't recognize those fields, that's okay.

Comment: That is exactly my question. I wonder why user  and item ids are explicitly excluded in the Google code tutorial.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's probably to avoid over-fitting. You wouldn't want to train a user-specific model (nor a item-specific model) for several reasons: 1) they tend to not generalize as well and 2) they make it difficult to accommodate new people and items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you have shared, the goal is to fit a linear regression to the discovered factor values so that a novel set of factor values can be used to predict the rating. In this kind of setup, you don't want information about which samples are being used; the only crucial information is the training features (the factor scores) and the rating (the training/test label). For more on this topic, take a look at "[Dimensionality reduction using non-negative matrix factorization for information retrieval](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/973042)."

If you included the movie ids and user ids in as features, your regression would try to learn on those, which would either add noise to the model or learn that low ids = lower score etc. This is possible, especially if this ids are in some kind of order you're not aware of, such as chronological or by genre.

Note: You could use movie-specific or user-specific information to build a model, but you would have many, many dimensions of data, and that tends to create poorly performing models. The idea here is to avoid the problem of dimensionality by first reducing the dimensionality of the problem space. Matrix factorization is just one method among many to do this. See, for example, PCA, LDA, and word2vec.